# Kivy Disable background fading on popup open

Tags: python, kivy

I don't know if  im putting it correctly. Usually when ever a popup or modal view is opened, the window background is then faded until popup is dismissed. I would like to know if there's a way to disable it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If using a Kivy version before 2.0.0, you can easily disable the background by making the [background color](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.modalview.html#kivy.uix.modalview.ModalView.background_color) transparent:

```
MyModalView(background_color=(0, 0, 0, 0))
```

or:

```
<MyModalView>:
    background_color: 0, 0, 0, 0
```

Starting at Kivy 2.0.0, this property has been renamed to `overlay_color`, but otherwise works exactly the same.

Comment: Yeah that did it. Thanks

Comment: This has been changed to `overlay_color` in 2.0.0, with `background_color` now affecting the background of the widget itself.